# "Read Only Database" Vs "Read and Write database" Configuration in mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

We are using two databases one is as *`read-only`* and the second one is for "*`read and write`*" and able to achieve what we are getting.

But sometimes our read-only database took more time to execute the same query and looks like queries going to the queue kind of thing.

Does it due to we are using high configuration "Read, Write " database as compare to "Read-only" Database. `(Amazon RDS)`

- we tried to found the article or any post but we couldn't find it. Can you help me to understand, please. because my theory says it is something if you put water from a Big pipe to small pipe then in any of the time it could create the problem.

Comment: Are they the same queries with the same schema, data and indexes? If not, they're not comparable. When you say "read-only" do you mean a [read replica](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/read-replicas/) or something else?

Comment: Yes same query , it is replica of "read and write database" for read only

Comment: It could be that the cache on the replica is not yet warmed up. There was an article about this recently: https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/06/25/adaptive-hash-index-on-aws-aurora/

Comment: When you say "sometimes", how often? And "more time" is it like 10 ms vs 20 ms or 10 ms vs 200 ms? Is it always the follower that's slower, or is the leader also sometimes slower? I ask because some performance fluctuation is expected. Have you done the usual steps of checking the slow query log and cache hit rates? Are [the table statistics](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html) up to date and [tables optimized](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimize-table.html)?

Comment: @Schwern it happen twice in last month only "10 ms vs 200 ms", only follower is slower not leader as leader has the better configuration than follower

Comment: Does the `read-only` server configuration is lower than the `read and write` server? Since the `read-only` does all the query part it should be better configuration than main server (read and write)

Comment: @James server is same just database is different

Comment: what instance you are using for both?

Comment: Server is on Heroku and database M4 Large (Read & Write) && T2 Mid (Read Only)

Comment: Ahhh... Since you have 8GB RAM on your (Read & Write) and Only 4GB on (Read Only). Often the Query is been fetched from Read Replica so that it should be more powerful than (Read & Write). It is same concept as Master- Slave Replication.

Comment: @James I did not get you what you want to say configuration is good or it should be change ?

Comment: Change.. make the (read only) higher

Comment: Actually, read-only is used when your application hits the db mostly on select rather than update or insert, so when read-only is added the leader will take care of write operation and the follower will take care of reads to balance the workload if you have higher follower the leader can do write operations without any lags due to read request is taken care by follower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Server is on Heroku and database M4 Large (Read & Write) && T2 Mid (Read Only) – [Arvind 7 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57247024/read-only-database-vs-read-and-write-database-configuration-in-mysql?noredirect=1#comment100994920_57247024)

[Your databases are on different "hardware"](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/), they'll have different performance.

The most significant different I see is memory: 4 vs 8 GB. This will affect how much caching each database can do. Your leader (read & write) has more memory and can cache more. Your follower (read only), with less memory, might have things pushed out of cache that your leader retains.

There is also network performance. t2.medium is listed at "low to moderate" while m4.large is "moderate". What that actually means I have no idea except that the T2 has less.

Finally, a T2 instance is ["burstable"](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) meaning it's normally running at about 20% CPU capacity with bursts to maximum performance using CPU credits. If you start to run out of CPU credits in [standard mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-standard-mode.html) (the default for T2) CPU performance will drop. It's possible your T2 follower is in standard mode and periodically running low on CPU credits.

Comment: @Arvind I'm curious if it was something concrete like running out of CPU credits.

Comment: it was related to cpu usages